# play framework 1.3 precompile java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, playframework

I'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when trying to compile all of a sudden.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Here is the command I'm running.
play clean works okay

```
Tzachs-MacBook-Pro:qa tzachs$ play precompile
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.3.4, https://www.playframework.com
~
~ using java version "1.8.0_111"
objc[18309]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10506b4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1051334e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-08-17 09:51:14 INFO  play:308 - Starting /Users/tzachs/personal/test
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/Users/tzachs/work/play-1.3.4/framework/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
2017-08-17 09:51:15 INFO  play:308 - Precompiling ...
2017-08-17 09:51:30 ERROR play:457 - Cannot start in PROD mode with errors
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.StringBuilderWriter.toString(StringBuilderWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:779)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:803)
    at play.libs.IO.readContentAsString(IO.java:53)
    at play.libs.IO.readContentAsString(IO.java:43)
    at play.vfs.VirtualFile.contentAsString(VirtualFile.java:181)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.refresh(ApplicationClasses.java:206)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.<init>(ApplicationClasses.java:198)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses.getApplicationClass(ApplicationClasses.java:51)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:480)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:300)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:430)
    at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:605)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:308)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:160)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran precompile with -Xmx4g and it worked fine.
Like this

```
play precompile -Xmx4g
```